# How to place image in Grid.Row but to keep it responsive WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, responsive

I'm working on a WPF app and I would like to place a user-icon next to a logged in username. I couldn't make it responsive at all and somehow it looks too large on my window.

This is how it looks in Expression Blend (it looks large even in design mode):

[image]

Here is my code:

> [TextBlock Text="User"]
>
> [TextBlock Text="*Current username from database*" ]
>
> [Rectangle as user icon, Background="Green"]

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
           Margin="5,5,34,0"
           x:Name="lblUser"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Text="User:"
           Foreground="White"
           FontSize="13"
           d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" />
<Rectangle Stroke="#83D744"
           Grid.Row="3"
           RadiusX="0"
           RadiusY="0"
           Margin="6,24.69,34,10"
           d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#5000" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<Image Name="imgExit"
       Grid.Row="3"
       Source="/MyDesktopApp;component/Images/user-icon.png"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       MaxHeight="35"
       MaxWidth="35"
       Margin="15,5,0,10"
       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
<TextBlock Foreground="White"
           Margin="8,40,34,4"
           x:Name="lblLoggedInUser"
           Grid.Row="3"
           FontSize="17"
           FontWeight="Bold"
           Text=""
           TextAlignment="Right" />
```

This is how it looks when I run the application (on my 22'' monitor) - really bad:

[image]

And this is how it looks when I run it on a smaller monitor like 17'':

[image]

How could I make it responsive on every size of screen? On 22'' it looks really bad.

Comment: I would use vector instead of the image, they scale very nicely and don't lose quality.

Answer (score -1):

You set the Image to an absolute position, I don't think you understood how the Grid works yet.

Use something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*"
                       MinHeight="80" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               Text="User" />
    <Border Grid.Row="1"
            Padding="8"
            BorderBrush="Green"
            BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"
                                  MinWidth="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="***" Stretch=""Fill/UniformToFill />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Admin" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: with example I posted ( rectangles etc) it is impossible to achieve that?

Comment: Why you just don't try my example or search a bit more XAML language, what you posted above isn't that well written at all

Comment: @Daniel, I tried billy_'s example, but it didn't worked for me also, could you explain us little bit how that might worked in billy's case, I mean by editing his code, how that might looks like or whatever. Thanks